# Как вынести повторяющийся код в отдельную функцию?

Tags: java

и после вызвать в каждом методе (BeatCook,BeatFаrmer)

```
            BeatCook.setOnMouseClicked((new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (foodList.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("список блюд пуст, увы");
                }
                else {
                    cook.eat(foodList);
                    List.remove(List.size() - 1);
                    ListFood.setItems(List);
                    }
                }
            }));
            BeatFarmer.setOnMouseClicked((new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if (foodList.isEmpty()) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("список блюд пуст, увы");
                    }
                    else{
                            farmer.eat(foodList);
                            List.remove(List.size() - 1);
                            ListFood.setItems(List);

                    }
                }
            }));
```

Comment: Если менять как то реализации анонимных классов не собираетесь, можно поставить один обработчик для   BeatFarmer  и  BeatCook

Comment: менять реализации не собираюсь, а что вы имели ввиду под одним обработчиком ?

Comment: Или просто вынесите код в отдельный метод и вызывайте, хотя не думаю, что это оптимально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как то так, возможно где то ошибки

```js
  EventHandler<MouseEvent> eventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
         @Override 
         public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
            if (foodList.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("список блюд пуст, увы");
                }
                else {
                    cook.eat(foodList);
                    List.remove(List.size() - 1);
                    ListFood.setItems(List);
                    }
         } 
      };  
 
BeatCook.setOnMouseClicked(eventHandler);
BeatFarmer.setOnMouseClicked(eventHandler);
```